# Android eclipse. Error when running my application

Tags: android

I cant get my application to work, but theres no error message in the development.
Im trying to learn how to link my page to another page.

[image]

TMactivity page 1.

```
  public class TmActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageButton NewPage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

     @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.NewPage = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.widget38);

    this.NewPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



public void onClick(View WebView) {

Intent i = new Intent(TmActivity.this, New.class);

startActivity(i);

}

});

}

}
```

// Page 2:

```
 public class WebView extends Activity {

        public class New extends Activity {

            /** Called when the activity is first created. */

            @Override

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.web);

            }

            }
    }
```

//first xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget37"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:layout_y="387dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget38"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="69dp"
        android:layout_y="386dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget39"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="151dp"
        android:layout_y="386dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget40"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="242dp"
        android:layout_y="383dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget43"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="47px"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="Teknikmagasinet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_x="74dp"
        android:layout_y="11dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget44"
        android:layout_width="203px"
        android:layout_height="30px"
            android:text="nyheter"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:layout_x="34dp"
        android:layout_y="77dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/widget45"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff33cc00"
        android:layout_x="44dp"
        android:layout_y="143dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget46"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="47px"
        android:background="#ffcc6600"
        android:text=" emil bergstrlm  han &#228;r kung "
        android:hint="phuong"
        android:layout_x="13dp"
        android:layout_y="255dp" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

// second xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tm.com"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget38"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
    android:text="Second Page"
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    sting xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

        <string name="hello">Hello World, TmActivity!</string>
        <string name="app_name">Tm.com</string>
        <string name="main_title">My Main Title</string>
    </resources>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: instead of your code U need to post your error log.

Comment: I think U forgot to register your activity in your manifest.xml file.

Comment: open terminal, type `adb locat` and find the error (errors start the line with "E/"). If you open terminal and type `adb logcat` then try to start the app (with terminal open) you'll be able to see where the error occurs.

Comment: [2012-02-10 17:08:29 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /Users/zamilio/Documents/workspace/tm/AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
[2012-02-10 17:08:29 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-02-10 17:11:53 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-02-10 17:12:01 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-02-10 17:12:10 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

[2"

Comment: eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=sv_SE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/zamilio/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/zamilio/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

Error
Fri Feb 10 17:14:12 CET 2012
Parser exception for

Answer (score 0):

//remove this life from your second activity

```
public class WebView extends Activity {
```

and register New in your manifest.xml

Comment: [2012-02-10 17:08:29 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /Users/zamilio/Documents/workspace/tm/AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
[2012-02-10 17:08:29 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
[2012-02-10 17:11:53 - tm] Error in an XML file: aborting build.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to open a new activity from an already running activity (Switching your page)? Try this.

**Activity Main.java :**

```
package tm.com 

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TmActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button butn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        butn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TmActivity.this, New.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Layout Main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="name" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In Application Manifest :** *Modify the manifest in the application bracket to look like this.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TmActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>      
        <activity android:name=".New"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: 02-10 17:26:38.690: D/dalvikvm(538): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-10 17:26:39.580: D/AndroidRuntime(538): Shutting down VM
02-10 17:26:39.580: W/dalvikvm(538): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-10 17:26:39.610: E/AndroidRuntime(538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 17:26:39.610: E/AndroidRuntime(538): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application tm.com.Main: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tm.com.Main
02-10 17:26:39.610: E/AndroidRuntime(538):

Comment: `Main` is replaced with the name of your class, I put it there as a dummy name, you can replace it with `TmActivity` (everywhere you see me put `Main`, such as `android:name="Main"`, and `Intent(Main.this,..);`, etc.

Comment: I've edited it to have the name of your activities in both the manifest and java class.

Comment: /Users/zamilio/Documents/workspace/byta/AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/icon').

Comment: ... That has nothing to do with page switching, whatever you named the icon that is supposed to appear in the application tray on the device, that's what they are saying is missing, so just replace that name with whatever you call your icon. For the purpose of the question, that is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I tried to copy your code into a new application just to understand how to do it. ublic class BytaActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button butn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        butn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(BytaActivity.this, New.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BytaActivity.this, New.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0); fail on NEW class to

Comment: i removed import android.R and it helped with the name on Main that i recalled as the public name. 
but New is still failing

Comment: This isn't a whole code, that's the point, it's enough of the code that you should be able to add the parts where I mentioned to your existing project. The last error you said you had, with the drawable icon not found... All you need to do is create any random image in your drawable folder and call it icon, then it'll work.

Comment: no i have looked at some video tutorial on youtube and learn a lite more. so i started a new project with the same purpose. And this project is alot of work, but it is a school project so i hope i could make a good application. Thank you again